# Can okhttp response body data be read after the call was cancelled?

Tags: android, okhttp, okio

In okhttp interceptor code, is it possible, after a call was cancelled, to read whatever partial response data might have been returned by the server?

The end goal is to cache partial content so that we can later resume with an http range request.

Answer (score 0):

Use Network inspector to see it .

[image: Please see the attached image .Hope you will get it]

Comment: this doesn’t answer the question - I’d like to know whether, after the Call has been canceled, is it possible to read whatever data might be in the underlying response body Buffer, or whether it’s “too late” because the buffer has already been cleared.

Comment: I don't think there will be any data if the API call has been canceled.